# std::vector emplace and std::vector emplace back with pair

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, emplace

I have this code:

```
std::vector<std::pair<const std::string, int>> vec;

vec.emplace_back("a", 1); //success
vec.emplace(vec.end(), "b", 2); //compile error

vec.emplace_back(std::make_pair<const std::string, int>("c", 3));  //success
vec.emplace(vec.end(),
     std::make_pair<const std::string, int>("d", 4)); //compile error
```

Can you explain me why?

Comment: It would help if you told us *what* errors you get. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the full, complete and unedited build output.

Answer (score 6):

Other than [std::vector::emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), [std::vector::emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) requires the element type meet the requirement of [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable), but `std::pair<const std::string, int>` has `const std::string` as its first element then doesn't satisfy that.

> Type requirements

> - T (the container's element type) must meet the requirements of [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable), [MoveInsertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable) and [EmplaceConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EmplaceConstructible).